# Variable assigned inside ssh command doesn't return proper value

Tags: ssh, scripting, quoting

I'm executing the below command in the `ssh` part of my script. The command is meant to cut the file size from `ls` option and storing it to a variable. Then print the variable:

```
echo "Enter srouce file";
read src_file;
src_size =`ls -latr $src_file | awk  '{ print $5 }' `;
echo "The source file size is $src_size ";
```

This works fine when it is executed on the command line.

When I try the same command inside a script via `ssh`:

```
ssh user@server "echo "enterfile";read src_file;echo "enter path ";read path;cd $path;src_size=`ls -latr $src_file | awk  '{ print $5 }' ` ; echo The source file size is $src_size;"
```

This fails. It stores some local temporary value and returns the same instead of correct file size.

Answer (score 3):

Use a script to avoid messing up your command with quoting issues.

It's cleaner, more manageable and looks better :)!

E.g. just do this:

```
echo "Enter source file"
read src_file
ssh user@server 'bash -s' < /path/to/local_script.sh "$src_file"
```

Contents of `local_script.sh`:

```
#!/bin/bash
src_file="$1"
src_size =`ls -latr $src_file | awk  '{ print $5 }'`
echo "The source file size is $src_size "
```

Don't forget to add the path to your `local_script.sh` :)

Comment: I'm afraid that in this way you are asking the name of the file from the script and not from the keyboard

Comment: yeah you're right, i'll fix that

Answer (score 2):

You can't nest double-quotes inside other double-quotes without doing some escaping - and by putting backticks inside double-quotes, they're getting evaluated on the local machine rather than the remote.

Something more like this should do what you're trying to accomplish:

```
ssh user@server 'echo "Enter file: "; read src_file; echo "Enter path: "; read path; cd $path; src_size=`ls -latr $src_file | awk  "{ print \$5 }"`; echo "The source file size is $src_size;"'
```

Note that I needed to change the `'{ print $5 }'` to `"{ print \$5 }"`, escaping the `$` because it's now inside double quotes rather than single and I don't want the `$5` to be interpretted by the shell.

Comment: he could also use `ssh user@server 'echo "Enter file: "; read src_file; echo "Enter path: "; read path; cd $path; src_size=\`ls -latr $src_file | awk  '"'"'{ print \$5 }'"'"'\`; echo "The source file size is $src_size;"'`...

But then, i'd rather recommend that he'd never have to look at this messy pile of code again :D

Comment: Yeah, I upvoted your answer as well - it's just as correct  :)